# Digital Comparator with Carry - How to fill the table correctly?

Tags: assembly, logic, cpu, processor, alu

We got a comparator which compares `4 bit` binary numbers (`A_3, A_2, A_1, A_0` and `B_3, B_2, B_1, B_0`). The result is the output signal `C_i` which has the value `1` if `A > B`.

The arithmetic-circuit is supposed to be made up by connecting `4` identical `1 bit` arithmetic-modules. Each of these `1 bit` modules have the inputs `A_i, B_i, C_i-1` and the output `C_i` with `i=0,1,2,3`. So, the carry outputs will be taken of the less significant digit `i-1`.

**Given is `A=0100` and `B=0010`. Fill the following table whereby `C_i-1` bit is supposed to be chosen by you in a reasonable way. The carry `C_i` is `1` exactly when we have `A > B`.**

I filled the table as good as I could but I have no idea how to do it with `C_i-1`...

I have read in our readings and what it's saying about `C_i-1`:
For the compare-operations `<, ≤, ≥, >` a subtraction is executed and the result is read from Carry-out `C_i-1`

So please tell me did I fill the table correctly? Because this is a task from old exam and it has many other sub tasks. If I do the beginning (this table) wrong, then everything else will be wrong too! :(

[image]

I choose C_i-1 like that because I look first row A=0 and B=0, so 0-0 = 0 that's why C_i-1 =0. Second row we have A=1 and B=0, 1-0 = 1 so C_i-1=1. Then we have A=0 and B=1, 0-1 = -1 but here is problem with this, if it's correct at all : / Don't know please help me..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common arithmetic predicates <, ≤, ≥, >, = are normally implemented with a subtraction.

There are two main ways to perform a subtraction: **A)** Using a subtraction module or **B)** Using an adder.

You didn't specify what kind of 1-bit module are you using, but from the text

> The carry C_i is 1 exactly when we have A > B

<sub><sup>Note that it should be **A ≥ B**</sup></sub>

we can deduce that they must be adders (full adders to be nitpicking). 
If they were subtraction modules the carry-out would have been 0 when *A≥B* because there is no borrow for the MSb when *A≥B*.

The subtraction *A - B* is performed as *A + -B* where *-B* is the two's complement of *B*.
In turn *-B* is performed as *~B + 1* where *~B* is the NOT of *B*.
Thus *A - B = A + ~B + 1*.

Getting *~B* from *B* is easy, it's just a matter of using a bunch of NOT gates (in truth they are XOR gates). However an adder only perform addition between two numbers (*A* and *B*), not three (*A*, *B* and 1).
We can overcome this issue by noting that **if we set *C<sub>-1</sub>*, the carry in of the first full-adder, to 1** (when normally is 0 for additions) we can add 1 to the result.

Thus the table is

```
        3   2   1   0
----------------------
Ai      0   1   0   0     
Bi      0   0   1   0

Ci-1    1   0   1   1
~Bi     1   1   0   1

Ri      0   0   1   0
Ci      1   1   0   1
```

C<sub>3</sub> is 1 and indeed 4 ≥ 2.

We can also try comparing 2 and 4:

```
       3   2   1   0
----------------------
Ai      0   0   1   0     
Bi      0   1   0   0

Ci-1    0   1   1   1
~Bi     1   0   1   1

Ri      1   1   1   0 
Ci      0   0   1   1
```

Here *C<sub>3</sub>* is 0 since 2 < 4 (and the result -2).
Finally if *A = B* we have *C<sub>n</sub> = 1* since *A + ~A + 1 = 2<sup>n</sup>-1 + 1 = 2<sup>n</sup>* where *n* is the number of bits of the comparator. *2<sup>n</sup>* is a *n+1* bits number with only the MSb set, and the MSb is *C<sub>n</sub>*.

Comment: Oh my god, finally after several days I understand it and I only understand it because of you! I have asked this question on so many other forums and nothing has helped me. I will write the exam very soon and if I pass it I'd really like to give you a little reward for this answer. For now, I can only give you a fat lovely + and an accept mark! :-) Really you saved me already with this answer, very big thanks.

Comment: Just one last question, you wrote in small letters: "Note that it should be A ≥ B". This is the case even if the task clearly says ">"?

Comment: Usually, we require *Cn* to be set when A>=B, because that's natural when we use adders for a comparator. One can arrange to have *Cn* set only when A>B but that's unusual, you should check your notes or ask the professor. I'm a bit out of context here.

Comment: @Margaret Bloom First table, line of Ci-1: Shouldn't it be 1 0 0 1 instead of 1 0 1 1?

Comment: @cnmesr I believe it should be 1 0 1 1 as A0 is 0, ~B0 is 1 and C-1 is 1 giving R0 = 0 and C0=1. Correct me if I'm wrong, it's easy to make a mistake :)